# Can You Determine from Master Google Sheet What Other Sheets Reference It?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a master sheet that I use that pulls from a few different tables from a central DB into a consolidated reference table in a google sheet.  I have several separate google sheets for various different functions that pull different pieces of data from the master sheet using IMPORTRANGE() function.

I want to insert a new field (column) to the master table, but that will potentially break a lot of the downstream formulas on the sheets that reference it.  In order to make sure I get everything, is there a way to determine what sheets are importing from the master?

When I setup the initial importrange link, I have to grant permission between the two...am hoping there is something I can lookup to give me a list of potential impacts?

Comment: Kindly share sample spreadsheet and the desired output?

Comment: Not sure if I can do that...it's like if I was using 5 different files.  File A, Tab 1 is the master sheet.  Then I have File B, File C, File D, File E, all of them have tabs/sheets that use IMPORTRANGE against File A, Tab 1.  I want to add columns to File A, Tab 1 but I don't know all of the downstream files I need to check.  Is it just File B-E, or is there File F, G, and H?  All of them use VLOOKUP formulas, so the IMPORTRANGE would mess up the formulas within each of those files.

Comment: Do you mean you want to search the files B-H to check if its referencing the Master Sheet from file A?

Comment: I guess that's one approach that could work, sure!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the need to edit a spreadsheet that has many links between sheets.
Google Sheets does not have a built-in mechanism to display these links.

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the formula search (Ctrl + H) to find all links to a specific sheet.

[image]

Also you can use the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const cons = ss.getSheetByName('Links');
  let aName = as.getName();
  let fName = aName + "'!";
  let arr = [];

  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    let sName = sheets[i].getName();

    let data = sheets[i].getDataRange().getFormulas();
    for (let j in data) {
      for (let k in data[j]) {
        let formula = data[j][k];

        if (formula.includes(fName)) {
          let r = j * 1 + 1;
          let c = k * 1 + 1;
          Logger.log(sName + ": R" + r + ":C" + c + formula);
          let adr = "R" + r + ":C" + c;
          arr.push([sName, adr, formula.slice(1)]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(arr);
  cons.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Add the "Links" sheet beforehand.
Then open the master sheet and run the code.
Any formulas in other sheets that reference this master sheet will appear on the Links sheet.

**Upd**
[Sample sheet I created for this question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxX1wgC8uqEo9Wd6MnK59dnFTb11Zud_JUr4XVi5qAQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think this might work if it was a 1:Many but it's really a Many:1.  Check out my comment under the main question, it might provide more context.

Comment: I added a second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Apps Script** that will scan files and check if it is referencing the Master Sheet.

**Example:**

Here I have 4 files named:

1. 68445559_Main
2. file1
3. file2
4. file3

In 68445559_Main, I have this cell that has "Hello World" in it:

**68445559_Main:**

[image]

**file1** and **file3** is using **IMPORTRANGE()** to get the value of `A1` in **68445559_Main**.

**file1:**

[image]

**file3:**

[image]

*(The 3 entries in file3 have the same formula)*

**file2** contains only "TEST" string:

**file2:**

[image]

To create a script, select **Tools** > **Script** editor from your Master Sheet then **Paste** the code below.

The script below will scan file1, file2, and file3, check if it is referencing the 68445559_Main and display the **Spreadsheet Name**, **Sheet Name** and the **Range**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetArr = ["file1 ID", "file2 ID", "file3 ID"]; // replace this with your sheet ids, example ["file B ID", "file C ID", "file D ID", "file E ID", "file F ID", "file G ID", "file H ID"]
  var result = [];
  sheetArr.forEach(sheetId =>{
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    var masterSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    var importRangeStr = "=IMPORTRANGE.+"+masterSheetId+".+"
    var find = sh.createTextFinder(importRangeStr).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll();
    if(find != ''){
      result.push(find)
    }
  })
  var finalResult = result.flat();
  finalResult.forEach(res => {
    var sheet = res.getSheet();
    var spreadsheet = sheet.getParent();
    Logger.log("Master Sheet found! Spreadsheet Name: "+ spreadsheet.getName()+", Sheet Name: "
    + sheet.getSheetName()+ ", Range: "+ res.getA1Notation());    
  })

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)